# The HTTP request must contain a user-specific secret - Error in fortify

Tags: ajax, csrf, fortify

I have below code in my applicaton.

```
makeAjaxRequest: function(url, data){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var response = Ext.JSON.decode(xhr.responseText);
        if (response) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Alert', response.message);
            Ext.getBody().unmask();
        }
    };
    Ext.getBody().mask('Loading...');
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Fortify is showing this error for this line

Error  - "The http request at * line * must contain a user-specific secret in order to prevent an attacker from making unauthorized requests"

```
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
```

How do i resolve this fortify issue?

Is it something Fortify is highlighting because it doesn't have full context of the application.

In my application i have SSO setup which is passing a user specific secret with every request. But fortify may not be aware of it and ends up flagging this as an issue.

Kindly advice on what is best way to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `XmlhttpRequest` when you can use `Ext.Ajax.request`?

Comment: @Alexander When i use Ext.Ajax.request too Fortify shows the same error in the line method:GET/ POST. Also we are submitting document uploads and hence constructing new FormData() and then setting lot of values in that and using XMLHTTPRequest. We can switch to Ext.Ajax but seems like it wont do much to resolve fortify issue.

Comment: Then you should remove the extjs tag as users knowledgeable in ExtJS cannot solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the setRequestHeader !!!

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(data);
```